# React native View embeding

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

Why I am getting error embeding views?

```
            <View>
            <view>
                <Text>Hello You!!</Text>
            </view>
            <view>
                <Text>Hello You!!</Text>
            </view>
            <view>
                <Text>Hello You!!</Text>
            </view>
        </View>
```

I am looking for something that embeds LinearLayout within linear Layout but so far I am getting errors like:

**Expected a component Class, got [object, object]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got the views wrong. It is `View` and no t`view`. It should be as following:

```js
<View>
  <View>
  <Text>Hello You!!</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
    <Text>Hello You!!</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
    <Text>Hello You!!</Text>
  </View>
 </View>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write exact the same what you wrote, capitol.

```
    <View>
    </View>
```

capital "V" closed with the exact the same word

```
    <Text>
    </Text>

     <ScrollView>
    <ScrollView>
```